# bsts - test for trend in time series

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

I am using the bsts package to analyze several time series, to find out whether the values in the series are increasing, decreasing or remaining stable along the time period.

I see I can extract a trend component from the model, which looks like it is increasing (code below). But how can I formally test the direction of the trend? Should I remove the local linear trend and instead do a regression against time? Or is there a way to answer that question using the trend component already extracted?

Here is one of the time series:

```
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2013 5.454450 5.351702 5.450414 5.490382 5.367216 5.404927 5.267974 5.211403 5.439326 5.394489 5.425333 5.413367
2014 5.365040 5.359957 5.388980 5.272279 5.337346 5.383114 5.211803 5.567671 5.446918 5.427461 5.490386 5.429216
2015 5.522443 5.432766 5.581413 5.307201 5.452850 5.426128 5.372678 5.524919 5.400167 5.453443 5.596288 5.424220
2016 5.633506 5.553917 5.553649 5.444297 5.551022 5.461216 5.503183 5.426033 5.454331 5.643385 5.575780 5.486073
2017 5.656180 5.411885 5.477615 5.437005 5.434144 5.404344 5.481005 5.437255 5.352800 5.485022 5.441534 5.472936
2018 5.366347 5.381583 5.401431 5.479976 5.439315 5.319484 5.421672 5.319448 5.574673 5.472161 5.479900 5.539380
2019 5.390139 5.429426 5.613977 5.343529 5.487940 5.624361 5.381285 5.366611 5.565688 5.503865 5.491821 5.486168
2020 5.475343 5.493866 6.010556 5.690947 5.656557 5.420500 5.453484 5.566972 5.369799 5.435967 5.613358 5.409345
```

And the code I used to extract the trend (from https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/), y is the time series above:

```
ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), y)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons = 12)
bsts.model <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss, niter = 500, ping=0, seed=2016)

burn <- SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.model)

components <- cbind.data.frame(
  colMeans(bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn),"trend",]),                               
  colMeans(bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn),"seasonal.12.1",]),
  as.Date(time(Y)))  

names(components) <- c("Trend", "Seasonality", "Date")
components <- melt(components, id="Date")
names(components) <- c("Date", "Component", "Value")

ggplot(data=components, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) + geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("") + xlab("") + 
  facet_grid(Component ~ ., scales="free") + guides(colour=FALSE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

Comment: Do you want to check whether the local linear trend is "statistically significant" (test the direction of the trend) or verify whether it explains the data better than a model without the local component (comparing to a linear trend)?

Comment: The first option, test the direction of the trend. I have a similar time series for each country in the world and want to see which ones are increasing, which ones are decreasing and which ones are stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by inspecting the draws more closely.

Let's take this apart:

```
colMeans(bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn), "trend",])
```

`bsts.model$state.contributions` is an array of shape `(iter, metric, obs)`.
`bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn), "trend", ]` Turns this into a `(non_burnin_iter, obs)` matrix.

The call to `colMeans` gets the average trend but you can extract any quantile or shares of properties as well:

```
m <- bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn), "trend", ]

# Average trend, what you are getting now.
colMeans(m)  

# Posterior probability that the effect of the local trend is positive
# Probably what you want though note that it's conceptually not the
# same as a p-value. It's more what people think 1-pvalue is.
colMeans(m > 0)  

# Lower bound of the 95% credible interval of the trend.
# Useful if you have a region or practical equivalence (ROPE).
apply(m, 2, quantile, p = 0.025)
```

Comment: I think I don't quite understand what the values in "m" are. I thought they represented the variation in the data that could not be attributed to seasonality, but since you compare the values themselves to 0 (m > 0), does that mean that they are actually slopes of the time series at that point (i.e. if the time series was decreasing, they would be negative)? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Regarding what `m` contains: The posterior draws of each component's contribution to the state, the prediction, i.e. everything that *can* be explained by the model. If you look at the seasonality component you can see whether at a given month the seasonality is positive or not (averaging to 0 of course). Likewise if the trend is positive at a given date then the predicted value increases.

Comment: The slope of the local linear trend isn't reported as far as I see but you could also have a model with a negative slope but a wide sd on state making the posterior negative so it depends on what you're trying to prove whether it's feasible, you could do something like `colMeans(m[, -1] - [, -ncol(m)] > 0)` To check if the effective slope is positive

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution (code below), please let me know if it makes sense.

Basically, for every point in the time series, I :

1. check if the lower limit of the 95% confidence interval is bigger than the upper limit of any of the points before it.
2. check if the upper limit of the 95% confidence interval is smaller than the lower limit of any of the points before it.

This way, if the time series is stable, both 1 and 2 should be small. If it is increasing, 1 should be bigger than 2. If it is decreasing, 2 should be bigger than 1. If it is fluctuating, both 1 and 2 should be big.

Let's say, if the difference between 1 and 2 is less than 10% of the time series length, I consider it stable.

Any reason this could give me misleading results?

```
components <- cbind.data.frame(
          apply(bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn),"trend",], 2, quantile, p = 0.025),
          apply(bsts.model$state.contributions[-(1:burn),"trend",], 2, quantile, p = 0.925))  
        names(components) <- c("Trend_lci", "Trend_uci")
        
        test_increasing <-
          sapply(1:nrow(components), function(i){ 
            
            any(components$Trend_lci[i] > components$Trend_uci[1:i])
            
          }) %>% sum
        
        test_decreasing <-
          sapply(1:nrow(components), function(i){ 
            
            any(components$Trend_uci[i] < components$Trend_lci[1:i])
            
          }) %>% sum
        
        test_increasing - test_decreasing
```

Comment: I'd stick to comparisons within each draw and *then* aggregate the results. It again depends on what you want to measure, if you have a continuous slight increase  (like 95% of the time series) and then a rapid crash back to the original level would you consider this increasing or constant?